# Swipebox - Loading HTML instead of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I chose [Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) as my lightbox because the requirements that I want is that it is swipable in mobile devices ad is responsive.

I mainly used this for images. However, I have a use case where I want to use Swipebox to show HTML.

Can this be done?

If this feature is not supported by Swipebox, are there any alternatives that support the featureset that I am looking for(swipeable + responsive + can show HTML)?

Answer (score 6):

Swipebox can display inline content. Probably is not documented but you can view it in this issue answer:

https://github.com/brutaldesign/swipebox/issues/248

```
<a href="#slide1" class="swipebox" title="Slide 1">...</a>
<a href="#slide2" class="swipebox" title="Slide 2">...</a>
<div style="display: none">
  <div id="slide1">Slide 1 Content</div>
  <div id="slide2">Slide 2 Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the option "`afterOpen: function () {}`" clean the content of `swipebox` and put my content there. Here is my code:

```
var html = $('the HTML');

$('.swipebox').swipebox({
    afterOpen: function () {
        $('#swipebox-slider').empty();
        $('#swipebox-slider').append(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this one ([bxSlider](http://bxslider.com)) but I have not tried it yet. It claims to support what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps your CSS isnt loaded correctly.

Check to make sure that you have the following code within your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="source/swipebox.css"/>
```

Hope this helps,
@_Sub